# combobox data from 2 related tables Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

i have 2 tables : Salesagent and Client which are related by id, each  sales agent have too many clients with the same id ,

i want to add combo box to display the salesagent, then another combo box that displays the clients of that salesagent

combosale is ok ..

comboclient , displays the **1'st field** of client table(only one not all of them ) ,when choosing only **1'st salesagent**

it  displays **nothing** when i choose **another salesagent even if it has clients related to it**

:(

i used :
Me.combmoclient = DLookup("[cname]", "[client]", "[salesagent]= '" & Me.Combosale & "'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Dlookup, it will just return the first value that matches your criteria, when really you need the whole set of clients for that sales agent.  Instead you should use the AfterUpdate() event of the combosale field to do something like this:

```
Private Sub Combosale_AfterUpdate()
Me.comboclient.RowSource = "SELECT cname FROM client WHERE id  = " & Me.Combosale.Column(1) & ";"
End Sub
```

In general, pure SQL queries are much faster than the Dlookup, Dsum, etc. functions. You will have a much more stable application if you stay away from them and write SQL code into your Access VBA.

Comment: comboclient now have the names of the clients of all  salesagents not the one i choose in combosale ,

Comment: i tried                                                                                    Me.Text35 = Me.Combosale.Column(1)

Me.comboclient.RowSource = "SELECT cname FROM client WHERE id = '" & Me.Text37 & "';" ... but still not working :(

Comment: If this was helpful could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

this vba solved the problem :)

```
Private Sub Combosale_AfterUpdate()
Me.comboclient.RowSource = "SELECT cname FROM client WHERE id  = " & Me.Combosale.Column(1) & ";"
End Sub
```

tooo many thanx for your help !!

Comment: Really you should accept the answer I posted rather than reposting the same code and accepting your own answer. Nobody gets any rep this way.

Comment: Thanks! Better late than never. ;)